# Cannot render components by mapping object ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a webapp using ethereum blochchain and ReactJS. In a page, inside componentDidMount() I collect data from blockchain and add it to an array named requests

```
typeof(requests) : object


console.log(requests) :(2) [Result, Result] 
0: Result
   0: "Title"
   1: "100000000000000"
   2: "0xbA439F3C91bF0732e5546721A09be207f69555ca"
   3: false
   4: "0"
   approvalCount: "0"
   complete: false
   description: "Title"
   recipient: "0xbA439F3C91bF0732e5546721A09be207f69555ca"
   value: "100000000000000"
   __proto__: Object
1: Result
   0: "New Request"
   1: "4000000000000000000"
   2: "0x8104Ce1f3d731A5C39501fddDdc14E2673555555"
   3: false
   4: "0"
   approvalCount: "0"
   complete: false
   description: "New Request"
   recipient: "0x8104Ce1f3d731A5C39501fddDdc14E2673555555"
   value: "4000000000000000000"
   __proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I tried to render components based on the elements of the requests using following code :

```
     <body>
              {this.state.requests.map((request, index) => {
            return (
              <RequestRow
                key={index}
                id={index}
                address={this.state.address}
                request={request}
                approversCount={this.state.approversCount}
              />
            );
          })}
            </body>
```

But this error occurs

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, address, request, approversCount}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

How to fix this?

RequestRow is not complete

It's implemented as

```
import React from "react";

const requestRow = (props) => <div>{props}</div>;

export default requestRow;
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are trying to render an object. For example: `const obj = {a: 1, b: 2}` and then something like `<div>{obj}</div>`. That's why you are getting the error - "Objects are not valid as a React child".

Comment: This looks fine, could you post the full error including the backtrace? What is the return value of the `RequestRow` render? Do you by any chance return anything other than JSX, `null` or an array?

Comment: `props` in requestRow in object so first you need to extract values from it and then you can use that values.  Try `const requestRow = ({ key, id, address }) => <div>{key}{id}{address}</div>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to write the code for empty array condition. You just need to write,

```
  <body> {
    this.state.requests.map((request, index) => {
        return ( <RequestRow key = {
                index
            }
            id = {
                index
            }
            address = {
                this.state.address
            }
            request = {
                request
            }
            approversCount = {
                this.state.approversCount
            }
            />
        );
    });
}</body>
```

Comment: can you provide the implementation for <RequestRow

Comment: import React from "react";

const requestRow = (props) => <div>{props}</div>;

export default requestRow;

Comment: <RequestRow> component is still under dev.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the comments and replays. Thanks [Ajeet Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873538/ajeet-shah) and [Priyank-Kachhela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8665589/priyank-kachhela) for pointing the error out. The error was due to the implementation of RequestRow component not the way of rendering it.